# what type of object should be used for a match-3 game (ios)

Tags: ios

I want to build a simple match-3 game for iphone.
Basically I expect around 50 indivivual 'objects' available to be tapped by the player.

My thinking is that custom buttons could be used, but maybe something better exists for this type of usage?

Basically all the objects will do is change position and be tapped for selection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a collection view and manage when a cell is selected to act like a button.